# Reversing the output of a function in python that is not a list

Tags: python, function, reversing

I will get a number for the output of this piece of code:

```
base = int(raw_input("Pick your base:  "))
base = str(base)
question = "Pick your number! (the base is "+base+" ):  "
number = int(raw_input(question))
def func(number):
    if number != 0: 
        sec = number/int(base)
        third = number - (sec * int(base)) 
        print third,
        func(sec) 
func(number)
```

I want to take the output (for example 2435) and reverse it (to 5342). I have tried the `a[::-1]` by assigning the `func(number)` to a variable and then printing that `variable[::-1]` however this does not seem to work:

```
x = func(number)   
print x[::-1]
```

That gives me:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: What value does `func` return? :)

Comment: It depends on the user input

Comment: No - look up `functions` in the language definition. What does *your* `func` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `func` is missing a `return` statement (and thus returns `None`). Without returning a value, you can't apply the index operator on it.